# Domain users, with access to a library, receive "Sorry, you don't have access to this page "

Tags: permissions

I have a AD Security Domain Group populated with a test user `account(test\johntester)`.  In one of my SP2013 sites, I've given the Domain Group '**edit**' access.  I do a '**Check Permissions**' and receive the following...

> Permission levels given to Tester, John (i:0#.w|testdomain\johntester)
>   *Edit*  Given through the "testdomain\sp tester2 group (c:0+.w|s-1-5-21-3111525-439037405-1252796590-36689)" group.

Logged in as that test account and I receive "*Sorry, you don't have access to this page*".  I cannot figure out why it would tell me that that account has edit rights but still cannot access the site.

Thanks

Comment: You might try checking the document library permissions vs. the site permissions.

Comment: you might be accessing specific sections or links that have broken inheritance from the parent.